# How to disable explicit stack traces on Ruby on Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, spree

I have a Ruby on Rails Spree commerce app where I have explicit stack traces enabled in production (e.g., instead of the "We're sorry but something went wrong" message there is a long stack trace with developer-friendly and user unfriendly information).

I remember that I activated this to see what went wrong in production, but now I want to disable it again. Unfortunately I cannot find nor remember how to do this.

I hope someone can tell me how to configure my app to redirect to the standard 500 and 404 pages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open `project_root/config/environments/production.rb`
And set `config.consider_all_requests_local = false`

Comment: Thanks that was it! Can I also do this on the server (via Rails Console)? Do not want to do a full deploy.

Comment: I have never tried this before so I am not sure if it works, but you can try typing this into the console: `Rails.configuration.consider_all_requests_local = false`